# Erlang, badmatch error when assigning list to a record

Tags: erlang

I am trying to assign the list ConnectedAtoms to the list connectedatoms inside the new created server_st record. But I get a badmatch error.

```
-module(server).
-export([loop/2, initial_state/1]).

-include_lib("./defs.hrl").


loop(St,{tryConnect,Atom}) -> 
    IsConnected = funcs:hasElem(St#server_st.connectedatoms,Atom),
    if
        IsConnected==true -> 
            {'EXIT',user_already_connected};
        IsConnected==false -> 
            ConnectedAtoms = St#server_st.connectedatoms ++ [Atom],
            St = #server_st{servername=St#server_st.servername,connectedatoms=ConnectedAtoms},
            {"Connected!",St}
    end;

loop(St, _Msg) ->
   io:format("Server got message.~n"),
   {ok, St}.



initial_state(_Server) ->
    #server_st{servername=_Server,connectedatoms=[]}.
```

Answer (score 7):

You get the bad match error as you are trying to reassign the value to St. Since Erlang being a functional programming language, once you assign a value to a variable you cannot change the value. Once the variable is bound to some value next '=' operators only matches the pattern.

```
St = #server_st{servername=St#server_st.servername,connectedatoms=ConnectedAtoms},
```

Change it to some other Variable

```
StConnected = #server_st{servername=St#server_st.servername,connectedatoms=ConnectedAtoms},
```